# Joining two RDD[String] -Spark Scala

Tags: string, scala, join, apache-spark, rdd

I have two RDDS :

```
rdd1 [String,String,String]: Name, Address, Zipcode
rdd2 [String,String,String]: Name, Address, Landmark
```

I am trying to join these 2 RDDs using the function : `rdd1.join(rdd2)` 
But I am getting an error :
 `error: value fullOuterJoin is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]`

The join should join the RDD[String] and the output RDD should be something like :

```
rddOutput : Name,Address,Zipcode,Landmark
```

And I wanted to save these files as a JSON file in the end.

Can someone help me with the same ?

Comment: `join` is defined on pair RDD, so your rdd1 is not of type  RDD[(String, T)] . You should map it, like this rdd1.map(v => (v, 1)) (or to another tuple, it depends on your task). If you explain your goal in more details (what you expect to get from the join), you may get more help.

Comment: @VitaliyKotlyarenko : Sorry for not clarifying it earlier. I just edited the question. Can you please help me with that ?

Comment: Your edit doesnt' help much. You don't have a `RDD[String]`, but two `RDD[String, String, String]`. Which field(s) do you want to join on? `Name` and `Address`, or just one of those?  You need to change the RDDs to have entries that are  tuples where the first of the pair is the key, and the rest is the `value`, then join will work.

Comment: I want to join on Name and Address both.

Answer (score 7):

As said in the comments, you have to convert your RDDs to PairRDDs before joining, which means that each RDD must be of type `RDD[(key, value)]`. Only then you can perform the join by the key. In your case, the key is composed by (Name, Address), so you you would have to do something like:

```
// First, we create the first PairRDD, with (name, address) as key and zipcode as value:
val pairRDD1 = rdd1.map { case (name, address, zipcode) => ((name, address), zipcode) }
// Then, we create the second PairRDD, with (name, address) as key and landmark as value:
val pairRDD2 = rdd2.map { case (name, address, landmark) => ((name, address), landmark) }

// Now we can join them. 
// The result will be an RDD of ((name, address), (zipcode, landmark)), so we can map to the desired format:
val joined = pairRDD1.fullOuterJoin(pairRDD2).map { 
  case ((name, address), (zipcode, landmark)) => (name, address, zipcode, landmark) 
}
```

More info about PairRDD functions in the Spark's [Scala API documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions)

Comment: Hello @Daniel : I am working on the RDD earlier by using this function, to come up with the output RDD1. Is there any way i can tweak this ? : i.map(r => { r._1 + "|" + r._2 + "|" + r._3+ "|" + sys.extractDocument(r._3) });

Comment: Yes, make the result of your map be a `(key, value)` pair.  This has been said several times, maybe you could take note of it?

Comment: @user2122466, sorry, I didn't understand your comment. Maybe you could improve your question?

Comment: @DanieldePaula `.map` does not  result to a PairRDD and yes to a RDD, are you talking about `.mapToPair`?

Comment: @deFreitas In Scala, an RDD of pairs is implicitly converted to PairRDD, so there's no need to call `mapToPair`, just a normal `map` returning a pair. `mapToPair` is needed if you are using the Java API.

Comment: To be more precise, in Scala an RDD of pairs has an [implicit conversion](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD$.html#rddToPairRDDFunctions[K,V](rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,V)])(implicitkt:scala.reflect.ClassTag[K],implicitvt:scala.reflect.ClassTag[V],implicitord:Ordering[K]):org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions[K,V]) to add the methods of [`PairRDDFunctiions`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions)