# Joining two (paired) RDDs in Scala, Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to join two paired RDDs, as per the answer provided here

[Joining two RDD[String] -Spark Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168889/joining-two-rddstring-spark-scala?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I am getting an error

error: value leftOuterJoin is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[

The code snippet is as below.

```
val pairRDDTransactions = parsedTransaction.map 
     {
              case ( field3, field4, field5, field6, field7,
           field1, field2, udfChar1, udfChar2, udfChar3) => 
             ((field1, field2), field3, field4, field5, 
                 field6, field7, udfChar1, udfChar2, udfChar3)   
     }      



val pairRDDAccounts  = parsedAccounts.map
     {
       case (field8, field1, field2, field9, field10 ) =>
         ((field1, field2), field8, field9, field10)

     }  



val transactionAddrJoin = pairRDDTransactions.leftOuterJoin(pairRDDAccounts).map {       
       case ((field1, field2), (field3, field4, field5, field6,
           field7, udfChar1, udfChar2, udfChar3, field8, field9, field10)) =>
             (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6,
           field7, udfChar1, udfChar2, udfChar3, field8, field9, field10)           

 }
```

In this case, field1 and field 2 are my keys, on which I want to perform join.

Comment: Here what you are missing, create tuple for your values as well.

Comment: `val pairRDDTransactions = parsedTransaction.map 
     {
              case ( field3, field4, field5, field6, field7,
           field1, field2, udfChar1, udfChar2, udfChar3) => 
             ((field1, field2), (field3, field4, field5, 
                 field6, field7, udfChar1, udfChar2, udfChar3))   
     } `

Comment: `val pairRDDAccounts  = parsedAccounts.map
     {
       case (field8, field1, field2, field9, field10 ) =>
         ((field1, field2), (field8, field9, field10))

     }  `

Answer (score 0):

Joins are defined for `RDD[(K, V)]` (`RDD` of `Tuple2` objects. In you case however, there arbitrary tuples (`Tuple4[_, _, _, _]` and `Tuple8[_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _]`) - this just cannot work.

You should

```
... => 
  ((field1, field2), 
     (field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, udfChar1, udfChar2, udfChar3)
```

and

```
... =>
  ((field1, field2), (field8, field9, field10))
```

respectively.